Enable/disable a QComboBox create inside a QStyledItemDelegate
I have a QTableView to admin employees. Each row in the table corresponds to one single person. The columns of the table hold different user infos and some columns contain combo boxes. These combo boxes are handled via delegates. The data for the table is within a QAbstractTableModel. Normaly the rows - and all its columns - are disabled, but in case I would like to edit/modify a line, I want to make all columns - in this single row - enabled. From the model I can make all columns - which are not handled via the deletage - enabled or disabled, but I don't know how can I access the combo boxes created via the delegate's create_edit method.
class ComboBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, owner, choices):
        super().__init__(owner)
        self.items = choices

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)
        super(ComboBoxDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent)
        editor.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.commit_editor)
        editor.addItems(self.items)
        #editor.setDisabled(True)
        return editor

    def commit_editor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        num = self.items.index(value)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(num)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.currentText()
        model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

        .......
        table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        table.sortByColumn(0, Qt.AscendingOrder | Qt.DescendingOrder)
        table.sortByColumn(1, Qt.AscendingOrder | Qt.DescendingOrder)
        horizontal_header = table.horizontalHeader()
        vertical_header = table.verticalHeader()
        horizontal_header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        vertical_header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        horizontal_header.setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.employeeModel = EmployeeTableModel(header, data)

        # Create sort filter for "name" column
        sort_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        sort_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        sort_model.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
        sort_model.setSourceModel(self.employeeModel)
        table.setModel(sort_model)

        table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ComboBoxDelegate(table, SKILLS))
        ..........


QAbstractItemView doesn't provide direct access to the editors based on their index, but, in normal conditions, it can be assumed as widget that is in the center of a visualRect(): 1. get the QModelIndex from the model's index(); 2. retrieve the visualRect(index) for that index; 3. find the childAt() of the viewport() at the center() of the rectangle above.

That sounds quite complicated, if at all doable. Is there any other way to add combo boxes to table cells?

If you want to keep the proper editor/model syncing, no, there's no more appropriate way, since setIndexWidget() requires to completely take care of both editor filling and model updates. Besides, it actually is not complicated and it is doable (otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it). Once you know the row/column you want to enable, the process is exactly as written above; assuming self is the table: index = self.model().index(row, column) rect = self.visualRect(index) widget = self.viewport().childAt(rect.center()) if isinstance(widget, QComboBox): widget.setEnabled(True).

Obviously, this is assuming that you're actually showing the combo boxes upfront through openPersistentIndex(), and the combos are disabled by default. Note that the standard item delegate already uses the QComboBox currentText() property, so you shouldn't need to override setEditorData() and setModelData() as long as the possible values are the same as in self.items.
